# How to access to menu items?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I created a menu of RCP application only in plugin.xml. How to access to items of this menu programicaly to change their texts and images at runtime?

Comment: If that's the answer, you should accept it, or edit your question with more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using command framework to contribute those menu items, you can use org.eclipse.ui.commands.IElementUpdater to change the text and image.